How can I create a minimal reproducible example for an Excel-related question?
I've seen quite a few Excel-related questions that insert an example spreadsheet as an image. (Most recently, this one, but almost every question tagged with excel seems to do this.)
To me, this makes the question hard to answer since I would have to populate an Excel spreadsheet by hand before trying to answer the question or test any solutions.
However, I'm not really sure what the alternative is. How can I create good example data for an Excel-related question?
I've read How can I create a table in a post, but I'm not sure how a markdown table could be easily converted to a spreadsheet.

For many cases, it's probably enough to provide the cell values in a regular (markdown) table. That would be copy&pasteable into a regular spreadsheet.

You can also use the Formatting Sandbox where you could create a dummy table and copy it into Excel to see how it behaves.
